# JavaScript -- slice time string to return HH:MM

Tags: javascript, date

I have a time/date string that is returned like so:

`"5/31/2016, 2:23:33 PM"`. I need only the HH:MM and am/pm, so `2:23 PM`

I am able to split the date off but not sure how I can remove the colon and seconds.

```
time = time.split(",")[0]; 
//time = " 2:23:33 PM";
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If starting with a date/time *string* and desiring to end with a time *string*, of the same format, consider the following [regular expression with two capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var dateStr = "5/31/2016, 2:23:33 pm";
var m = dateStr.match(/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):\d{2}\s+?(AM|PM)/i)
//                      ^-- 1                    ^-- 2
if (m) {
   console.log(m[1] + " " + m[2].toUpperCase()); // "2:23 PM"
}
```

Otherwise, if ever needing to deal with a proper date/time object I'd consider `moment.js` - and specify the appropriate conversion format.

I would *not* use `new Date(nonISO8601String)` for parsing as it is unreliable across browsers/localizations.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse the string and then output as a formatted string like this

```
var input = "5/31/2016, 2:23:33 PM";
var result = moment(input);

console.log(result.format("hh:mm a"));
//output: 02:23 pm
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2zbqvmt/)

Comment: If you are using moment.js to parse the string you should also tell it the format to parse, otherwise you are leaving it entirely to chance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As others have mentioned, although this answer does work as expected,  that may not be the case across all browsers and locales the same.

My recommendation would preferably to use one of the popular date libraries like [Moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com), which could be argued as the de facto standard at the present time for handling this.

**Using a Date Object**

While this is entirely feasible through a series of splits, regular expressions, etc, it may simply be easier to just use some of Javascript's built-in Date functionality (assuming that your format isn't going to vary wildly).

You could consider writing a function to parse your date as a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and then formatting it accordingly :

```
function formatDateStringAsTime(input){
  var date = new Date(input);
  // Determine if it is AM or PM
  var ampm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
  // Output what you need
  return (date.getHours() % 12) + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ampm;
}
```

Additionally if you want to ensure you have two digits (i.e. zero padded values), you can use a bit of slicing to change that :

```
// Using this approach will pad your hours and minutes with zeros if necessary
return ('0' + (date.getHours() % 12)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ampm;
```

**Example**

```
formatDateStringAsTime("5/31/2016, 2:23:33 PM"); // yields 2:23 PM
```

```js
var input = "5/31/2016, 2:03:33 PM";
input = formatDateStringAsTime(input);
console.log(input);

function formatDateStringAsTime(input) {
  var date = new Date(input);
  // Determine if it is AM or PM
  var ampm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
  return ('0' + (date.getHours() % 12)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ampm;
}
```

**Consider Date-specific Libraries**

As others have mentioned, if you are going to be performing this behavior frequently within your application, you might consider using a library like [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which are designed for exactly this.

Comment: `new Date(str)` is only well-defined over certain formats. I avoid this minefield for dates that are not ISO-8601.

Comment: Good answer, exactly what I suggested, however, might I recommend ditching the seemingly unnecessary if statements?

Comment: Thanks Brynden. I had used the if approach just to provide an idea for what was actually going on as I thought it might be a bit clearer for some folks as this wasn't at all an optimized approach.

Comment: thanks. works perfect except for one minor issue: when minutes are 0-9 they dont get prefixed with a "0". i.e 5:9 PM. just FYI

Comment: Right, if you want to explicitly pad them to two digits, you could use `("0" + (date.getHours() % 12)).slice(-2);` for the hours. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: You should never recommend parsing strings with the Date constructor or Date.parse, especially for a non–standard format.

Comment: youre right regarding your update. your code seemed to work fine in Chrome but IE Edge shouts because it expects "input" to be in a certain format I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two lines using this regex:

```
var a = new Date("5/31/2016, 2:23:33 PM");

var b = a.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/,' ');
console.log(b)
```

Comment: This answer expects correct parsing of a random string using the Date constructor and the value returned by *toLocaleTimeString* to adhere to a particular format. Neither assumption is supported by the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of strings using the Date constructor (and Date.parse) is largely implementation dependent and inconsistent across browsers so should not be relied upon. If parsing is required, use a bespoke function or library, there are plenty to choose from.

But reformatting a string doesn't require parsing, just extracting the required values. There are any number of simple ways to manipulate the string, here are two (note that leading zeros for hours are typically only used for 24 hour time formats):

```js
// Extract h:mm ap component of a string in m/d/y h:mm:ss ap format
function getTime(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return z(b[4]) + ':' + z(b[5]) + ' ' + s.slice(-2);
}

document.write(getTime('5/31/2016, 2:23:33 PM'));
```

And (though this doesn't add leading zeros):

```js
document.write(
  '5/31/2016, 2:23:33 PM'.replace(/[^\s]*,\s|:\d+\s/g,' ').trim()
);
```